# How to replace a value in an ArrayList (with multiple columns) with a new value, in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, multiple-columns

I have read many posts about updating a certain value in an ArrayList, when the ArrayList is single column. In my case, I have a multi-column ArrayList which is done by using the following JAVA code.

```
Class A{
           private List<double[]> ArrayList;

           double[] _array = {0.0, 1.0};
           ArrayList.add(_array);

           _array = {2.0, 5.0};
           ArrayList.add(_array);

           _array = {3.0, 8.0};
           ArrayList.add(_array);
}
```

Then my ArrayList looks like,
    {0.0, 1.0}
    {2.0, 5.0}
    {3.0, 8.0}

My problem is: I tried to replace the number 8.0 with a new number. And I don't think I can use "ArrayList.set(2, 8.0)" to achieve the goal, since it only works well when the ArrayList has a single column.

Any feedback and comments are welcome.

Comment: Hi all, the other short question, i.e. when I tried the similar code as written by user3334250, e.g. arrayList.set(0, new double [] {arrayList.get(0)[3]‌​, arrayList.get(0)[3] + arrayList.get(0)[1]}‌​); What happened is: although the value (of the index 3) is updated successfully, the size of my arrayList has been changed to 2 (from 8 which is the original size). I just cannot figure out the reason, and do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> You should select the array from the arrayList first.

```
double[] _array = ArrayList.get(1);
_array[1] = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tsadkan, and yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.get()` to get the array you're looking for.

You can then set a single value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner to change the value of 8.0 to 4.4

```
arrayList.set(2, new double[]{arrayList.get(2)[0], 4.4});
```

Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<double[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    arrayList.add(new double[]{0.0, 1.0});
    arrayList.add(new double[]{2.0, 5.0});
    arrayList.add(new double[]{3.0, 8.0});

    System.out.println("Before:");
    for (double[] d : arrayList) {
        System.out.println(d[0] + ", " + d[1]);
    }

    arrayList.set(2, new double[]{arrayList.get(2)[0], 4.4});

    System.out.println("After:");
    for (double[] d : arrayList) {
        System.out.println(d[0] + ", " + d[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
0.0, 1.0
2.0, 5.0
3.0, 8.0
After:
0.0, 1.0
2.0, 5.0
3.0, 4.4
```

Comment: Hi user3334250, thanks for sharing, and this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi again, the other short question, i.e. when I tried the similar code, e.g. 
arrayList.set(0, 
                     new double [] {arrayList.get(0)[3], arrayList.get(0)[3] +     
                     arrayList.get(0)[1]});

What happened is: although the value (of the index 3) is updated successfully, the size of my arrayList has been changed to 2 (from 8 which is the original size). I just cannot figure out the reason, and do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I Analyse your problem and perform such type program. You have to get all the properties and then edit it. Use HashMap for such operation is best way. I hope below code helps you...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RectangleL {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> lstShap = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,String> shape1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String,String> shape2 = new HashMap<>();
        lstShap.clear();
        shape1.put("width","30");
        shape1.put("height","40");
        shape1.put("infected","false");
        lstShap.add(0,shape1);

        shape2.put("width","20");
        shape2.put("height","49");
        shape2.put("infected","false");
        lstShap.add(1,shape2);

        System.out.println(lstShap.toString());
        shape1=lstShap.get(1);
        System.out.println(shape1.toString());
        shape1.put("infected","true");
        lstShap.set(1,shape1);

        System.out.println(lstShap.toString());
    }
}
```